# How to debug solidity line by line

Tags: debugging, windows-10, ethereum, solidity

There are many EThereum debuggers. But most of them are unable to perform symbolic debugging : this require to understand the links between opcodes and source lines as well as stack/memory and variables.

I’m not an EVM expert. How to debug line by solidity line and track variable content by name ?

This would be for debugging transactions with deployed contracts on mainet.

Comment: Do not say Remix. Most of the time [Remix is unable to use source code matching the deployed contract for an unknow reason](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/50257/25002) and work opcode by opcode instead.

Comment: Have you tried using Truffle's debugger yet? http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/debugging

Comment: @AdamKipnis : doesn’t Truffle only works opcode by opcode ?

Comment: You can do both. You can step through Solidity statements ('o' = Step over) or look at opcode evaluations (';' - Step instruction). At each step, you can print out the current stack data. It's a bit cumbersome to use, but is an alternative to Remix.

Comment: I've never heard of that requirement before. Do you have documentation to support that? I'm almost certain that all you need is the transaction hash and the source code. The blockchain has all of the information needed to reproduce the transaction. The source code is needed so Truffle can do the mapping. How the contract was deployed shouldn't matter.

Comment: @AdamKipnis an answer giving details step by step would be welcome. Including how to install without node.js on Windows. **[I’m thinking solving my problem with remix would be simpler](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/50257/25002)**